# Not able to append elements in python list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, counter

I am writing a program, to find the character that occurs maximum number of odd times, in a given string using python. However i am not able to append characters to a list, if two or more characters occur maximum number of odd times.

input used  : AAAbbccc

Error i am getting :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 18, in 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

```
inputString = input()

dict = {}

for i in inputString:
  if i in dict:
    dict[i] += 1
  else:
    dict[i] = 1


print(dict)
max = -1
lst = []
for i in dict:
  if(dict[i]%2!=0 and max<=dict[i]):
    if(max == dict[i]):
      lst.append(i)
    else:
      max = dict[i]
      lst = i

print(lst)
```

Comment: In line 21 you have an assignment 'lst' to 'i' which is not an array, then when when line 18 occurs lst is not an array anymore so it doesn't have an append method

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue that's working completely fine i'm getting error for line " lst.append(i) " where i am trying to append character into the list but i'm getting the above mentioned error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

1. Don't name variables after built-ins (even as an example). Use `d` or `dict_` instead of `dict`. Ditto `max`.
2. Your `max` (fixed at `-1`) will *always* be `<= dict[i]`, since counts are always `>= 1`.
3. You define `lst` as a list, then assign a string to it.

Much simpler, use `collections.Counter`, calculate the maximum value, then use `max` with a custom function:

```
from collections import Counter

inputString = input()
c = Counter(inputString)
print(c)

maxval = max(c.values())

def max_logic(x):
    cond1 = x[1] % 2
    cond2 = x[1] - maxval
    return cond1, cond2

key, val = max(c.items(), key=max_logic)
```

Example run:

```
print(key, val)

thisisateststring
Counter({'t': 4, 's': 4, 'i': 3, 'h': 1, 'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'r': 1, 'n': 1, 'g': 1})
i 3
```

The solution assumes a valid odd count *does* exist in your string. If it doesn't and you need to apply special treatment, you'll need to add additional logic. I leave that as an exercise.